# how to log binary data in linux

Tags: linux, binary, logging

I searched online for some software for logging in Linux, most of them were referring to logwatch to watch the logged data in the machine. 
The problem is that I am looking for a software which can log binary data coming from another machine !! any suggestions folks?

Comment: You'll have to be far more specific about what problem you're trying to solve. Would `nc -l some_port > /var/log/log_file` get you most of the way there? What else would you want the logging software to _do_?

Comment: I want the software to log all the binary messages I am getting from another machine , will this command do it?

Comment: What application is generating the messages?  How are they delivered (what protocol)?  The `syslog` utility is designed to receive both local and remote messages.

Comment: well the messages are radio frequency and I was thinking of using simple ssh configuration .

Comment: Are you expecting your logging server to keep track of source machine, date that the information was received, and so forth? Or does it just need to store a giant blob of growing data?

Comment: I want to log everything I get from the other machine, I used your solution  --> nc -l some_port > /var/log/log_file .. you can put it as the answer so I would accept it as the correct one :) thank you

Answer (score 0):

*Since feature requests to [mark a comment as an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82099/answering-comment-answered-questions) remain declined, I copy the above solution here.*

`nc -l some_port > /var/log/log_file`
–  sarnold